# Dont understand whats on in this haskell code

Tags: function, haskell, types

I have some haskell code Im trying to work my way thourgh but I dont have understand what is going in it.

```
type Bag a = a -> Int

emptyB :: Bag a
emptyB = \e -> 0

countB :: Eq a => Bag a -> a -> Int
countB b e = b e
```

I understand that the Bag type is a function that takes in a generic object and returns a Int and countB is basically a wrapper for Bag that gets the number of generic objects in that Bag. But I dont really understand anything past that. How do I modify whats in the bag? Or the bag itself? From what I figure adding to the bag would be something like

```
addB :: Eq a => Bag a -> a -> Bag a
addB bag num = bag (num+bag)
```

But this returns a int, when the add function requires a bag be returned. Can anyone explain to me how this works?

Comment: Perhaps you are assuming too much because of the type name "Bag".  Try rewriting it with `type Function a = a -> Int` instead of `Bag`.  Then try to inline everything - wherever you currently see `Bag a` replace it with `a -> Int`.  What do you think about the problem now?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't really get it and Im not really anymore cleared up on whats going on. Rewritting it as function instead of bag makes me more confused as to how to return a function object instead of a Int as that seems to be the only thing Ive managed to figure out -_-

Comment: It may be useful to realise that `countB` can be rewritten as `countB b = \e -> b e`.

Comment: `addB bag x y = (if x == y then 1 else 0) + bag y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Terms and Discussion**

```
type Bag a = a -> Int
```

Here `Bag` is not an object.  It is just a type - an alias for `a -> Int`.  If you have a value of type `a` it will compute and return a value of type `Int`.  That's it.  There is no Bag, no structure to which you can add things.  It would be better to not even call this a Bag.

```
emptyB :: Bag a
emptyB = \e -> 0
```

A function from any type to the constant number zero.

```
countB :: Eq a => Bag a -> a -> Int
countB b e = b e
```

In short, this is just function application.   Apply the function named `b` to the input `e`.

**Rewriting for fun and learning**

I appreciate that you can use functions to imitate structures - it's a common programming language class assignment.  You can take a `Bag a` and another `Bag a` then union them, such as returning a new `countB` by adding the counts of the two individual bags - cool.

... but this seems too much.  Before moving on with your assignment (did I guess that right?) you should probably become slightly more comfortable with the basics.

It might be easier if you rewrite the functions without the type alias:

```
emptyB :: a -> Int
emptyB = \e -> 0
-- or: emptyB e = 0
-- or: emptyB _ = 0
-- or: emptyB = const 0
```

Bag or no bag, it's just a function.

```
countB :: Eq a => (a -> Int) -> a -> Int
countB b e = b e
```

A function that takes an `a` and produces an `Int` can... be given a value (the variable `e` is of type `a`) and produce an `Int`.

Comment: You did it right, Ive been left to float with this class and its been killing me. This write up was very helpful thank you!