# How to define an unordered collection in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Wondering how you would define an unordered group/collection in Haskell, where by "collection" I mean it can have many copies of the same element, and the items are *unordered*. I know of the `List` data type in Haskell, but this is inherently ordered. I would like to see what the definition would look like for an *unordered* collection/group/list.

Comment: What does "unordered" mean to you exactly?

Comment: I know it's a good question. But there is `<ul>` in HTML. Basically it doesn't have the property of ordered, the most general meaning. When you have a group of students, there is no order to it, it is just a group. You can then order them by their name, or something, but by default you think of the list of students as unordered.

Comment: @LancePollard everything is ordered. When a collection is called "unordered" it really just means that the order is arbitrary -- it has no meaning

Comment: Wondering how you specify in Haskell that "order is arbitrary".

Comment: The HTML `<ul>` simply doesn't display numbers on every line when rendered, but the elements do have order. For example, you can swap two elements, and it will have a visual effect. If you want an "unordered collection", you have to specify precisely what it is.

Comment: Did you [Google this](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=unordered%20collection%20haskell) at all...?

Comment: Yes I have searched this extensively over the past few months here and there and haven't found anything on the topic.

Comment: @LancePollard generally it's a consequence of the underlying data structure. Unordered collections have no *inherent* benefit over ordered collections, so the only reason to use them is if you can exploit the arbitrary ordering to create useful behavior (usually for performance reasons). You can look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers

Comment: From [googling *unordered collection haskell*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=unordered+collection+haskell), it also gave [this introduction to `unordered-containers`](https://ocharles.org.uk/posts/2013-12-17-24-days-of-hackage-unordered-containers.html) by OCharles. You should have come to StackOverflow long ago, we just saved you months of searching!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54995025/dont-understand-whats-on-in-this-haskell-code#comment96749791_54995025

Comment: You can define an abstract data type of unordered collections, and you can define an operation to add an element to the collection.  But you can’t define any sensible operation to get an element out of the collection.  Any pure function that takes an element out of the collection will have to use some criterion to select this element, and that induces an implicit ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define it this way

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map

type MultiSet' a = Map.Map a Int
```

Just a mapping from a type `a` to an `Int`. In mathematics it would be something like *f* : *S* -> **N**. The elements you put into it must be ordable, that is because the underlying structure of the `Map` is defined by a binary tree. This shouldn't be a problem as you can forget about it when using the data structure. See the very extensive [documentation of Data.Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html) for functions to deal with our `MultiSet'`.

Now there is already a definition together with implementation for this and it is called [MultiSet](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.1/docs/Data-MultiSet.html). You can browse to its [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.1/docs/src/Data.MultiSet.html) code as well, there you see they defined it in an almost an identical way (they used the *strict* version of the map).

Alternatively you can use a hashmap, it will look like this:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as Map

type MultiSet'' a = Map.HashMap a Int
```

The elements you put into it do not need to be ordable, but hashable.

Comment: Note that there is a minor difference: a `MultiSet'` mapping an element to 0 would be different than one not mapping that element to anything, yet usually we want to consider them equal. One could define custom `Eq,Ord` instances to address this issue, using a `newtype`.

Comment: @chi You should indeed not map an element to 0. If you remove an element `x` from `MultiSet'` and you end up with 0 of those elements than you should remove `x` from the list/set of keys. I expect the package MultiSet (which I mentioned as well in my answer) to take care of this all.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a structure that has no reasonable order then why not compose a Map with a hash?

```
type MyBag a = Map (Int,a) Int
insert x mp = Data.Map.insertWith (+) 1 (hash x, x) mp
```

The above is a balanced binary tree with an order that depends on the hash of the value you have inserted.  The map itself is boring, along the lines of `data Map k a = Bin (Map k a) a (Map k a) | Nil`.

This said, I think you underspecified what you are looking for and what you hope to learn.  Your searches have probably yielded hashtables and unordered-containers - why aren't those sufficiently informative?